# tinymce autoresize plugin doesn't work correctly on backspace html img content

Tags: javascript, tinymce, autoresize

I use tinymce editor with autoresize plugin enabled. It work correctly with text, but when I insert an html content via execCommand, for example

```
 <div>
     <img src="/path/to/image  width="200px" height="160px"/>
 </div>
```

and then I delete it by backspace, tinymce remove correctly html node from iframe but autoresize plugin doesn't resize making smaller iframe height, now that it hasn't  html content of image.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588025/change-tinymce-editors-height-dynamically). There is an answer of mine with a function to adjust the iframe height of tinymce.