# How to make TinyMCE to fit content height when it's read only?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Please help because I'm stuck from hours. I have multiple count of text areas in one page. Each text area has different content inside which makes it with different height. When I init TinyMCE like this:

```
 tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        width: "870",
        readonly: true,
        theme_advanced_path: false,
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
        auto_resize: true
    });
```

All text areas are with same height and those of them which have more content has scroll inside. Any ideas how to rid of the scrolls and make the text area height as much as the content inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the function `resizeIframe` in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588025/change-tinymce-editors-height-dynamically). You will need to issue this code after the readonly editors have been initialized.

Comment: aha OK so there is no trivial solution for this.So if I understand right I need to make script that dynamically changes the size of the iFrame. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: that is correct - there is no built-in function to do this afaik