# Make TinyMCE Editor width fit the content dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, wysiwyg

How can TinyMCE fit his content when it's inside a absolute positioned container and also that the width keep updated during editing.

```
<div class="container">
    <textarea>This is my very long text that shouldn't be broken. This is my very long text that shouldn't be broken</textarea>
</div>    
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector:'textarea',
        plugins: "autoresize"
    });
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/charlesbourasseau/6a6187su/2

Answer (score 0):

<del>Make `width` to be 99% of the width of the containing element</del>

<del>In fiddle if you make `width` to be 98% it looks nice without any scrollbars.</del>

Use one of the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript) (I would go with the HTML5 canvas one), to get the width of the text currently entered inside the textarea (now the tinyMCE container).

After that use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139157/984049) to resize your tinyMCE iframe.

Comment: It does not really fit. It just take the whole place inside `.container`. What I want is that the editor only takes the needed space, and that it grows during writing.

Comment: maybe the answer in the other post will help. take a look at the link

Comment: Height is not a problem. I'm using the plugin `autoresize` and it works very well, but only for height... The width stays fixed.

Comment: if you can do something for the height, you can also do it for the width. take a look at the other link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="application/javascript" language="javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea#page_content",
    theme: "modern",
    width: 'auto',
    height: 300,
    plugins: [
         "advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
         "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
         "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
   ],
   content_css: "css/content.css",
   toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | l      ink image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons", 
   style_formats: [
        {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
        {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
        {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
        {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
        {title: 'Table styles'},
        {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
    ]
 });
</script>
```

This works for me..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please provide a jsfiddle. Your example is not working as I expect: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesbourasseau/6a6187su/3/

Comment: not how I would expect. The content inside TinyMCE is displayed on two lines. I would like to have only one line until I press enter.