# Cross browser issue with TinyMCE iframe resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

After I found a solution to resize my tinyMCE instances ( they are readonly ). I faced a problem that I can't solve from hours... When I **init** the tinyMCE everything is OK, but in **Internet Explorer** and early versions of **Chrome** this doesn't work

```
tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "advanced",
        readonly: true,
        theme_advanced_path: false,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
        autoresize: true,
        width: "870",
        setup: function(ed) {
            ed.onLoadContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                var iFrameID = "#" + ($(this).attr('id')) + "_ifr";
                $(iFrameID).height($(iFrameID).contents().find("html").height());
                //iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
            });
        }
    });
```

Also my Java Script attempt which is bellow the jQuery also not works.
I will be more than happy if anyone got solution for this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't use [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com)?

Comment: That's not a solution to my problem!

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? What do you mean with "not works"? Why the title reports Cross domain issue?

Comment: Sry... I mean Cross Browser ( now it's edited ) Not works means that in IE and early versions of Chrome the iFrame stays not resized. And I cant find solution that works in each browser...

Comment: what i see in docs is a property name theme_advanced_resizing set it to true.. it's rquired to make resizable tinymce

Comment: @vishalsharma: yes, but this enables the user to resize the window. here the editor shall get resized oninit without any user action

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799123/how-to-automatic-resize-tinymce

Comment: @Thariama You're helping me for 10010101 time! THANK YOU MATE! THANK YOU!

Comment: could you create a javascriot fiddle for this?

Comment: Today I'll post the configuration that I've made, but sorry I can't make fiddle because the project where I'm doing this not allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here is the configuration that worked for me!

```
 tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            theme_advanced_path: false,
            theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
            autoresize: true,
            readonly: true,
            width: "870",
            plugins: 'autoresize',
            autoresize_min_height: "200",
            autoresize_max_height: "50000",
            init_instance_callback: function(inst) {
                inst.execCommand('mceAutoResize');
            },
            setup: function(ed) {
                ed.onLoadContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                    var iFrameID = "#" + ($(this).attr('id')) + "_ifr";
                    $(iFrameID).contents().find("html").children().append("<base target=_blank>");

                   //The following row not works in IE - $(iFrameID).height($(iFrameID).contents().find("html").height());
                });
            }
        });
```