# How to increase height of tinyMCE dynamically with jquery on reaching bottom of viewable space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tinymce

How to increase height of `tinyMCE` dynamically with jquery on reaching end of available space?

i want to increase the height on reaching bottom of displayed space dynamically.

because i don't want to scroll it to view top contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set tinyMCE height: auto hopefully it works.

Comment: Follow these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799123/how-to-automatic-resize-tinymce,https://drupal.org/node/181204

Comment: you are sure about the link? does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

Set body and the Html height 100%, and the set the parent where  de tinyMCE is to a height of 100%. On the fildset and child elementes set to height 100%.

body,html{ height: 100%;}

fieldset{ height: 100%;}

Child element area write  { height:100%}

Note the parent element where you want to increase to bottom of the page must be also height: 100%

Comment: actually i want to increase height of working space of tinyMCE

Comment: Not the elements holding it

Comment: Is the same, make the height of the working space of tinyMCE to 100%, but be shore that the parent element (div , span, whatever is 100% too

Comment: i want to do more like if overflow-y occurs inside the tinymce working area then height increase by one line.

Comment: which i think need to do with tinymce js files

Comment: No, you don´t need. see what i do in this link http://jsfiddle.net/4AWvg/  . just adjust on your side....is very simple