# Update TinyMCE editor height

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have a custom plugin for TinyMCE that adds a custom button to the toolbar to upload images using AJAX.

This is my code:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src="'+response.url+'" />');
```

The problem is that after the image is added to the editor the editor height doesn't update. I must write anything or use Ctrl + A to update the height of the editor.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNveG.png

My TinyMCE settings:

```
'height'                => 150,

'autoresize_min_height' => 150,
```

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799123/how-to-automatic-resize-tinymce) for an answer

Answer (score 0):

The `autoresize` plugin doesn't dynamically resize on content insertion - it only makes sure the editor is taking up all the space it can inside it's parent element.

You'll need to add a line to your button code after your `execCommand` that invokes an editor resize event.