# TinyMCE 5 Manual Resize

Tags: tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE v5 and I'm unable to manually resize the editor by dragging the right-corner.

here is my setup:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.0.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.0.2/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>


tinymce.init({ 
    selector:'#client_report',
    resize: true,
    theme_advanced_resizing: true

});


<div class="well"  >
<h3>Client's Report</h3>
    <textarea    id="client_report" placeholder="Enter here the latest client's report"   >
    </textarea >
</div>
```

I tried with and without theme_advanced_resizing, but same result.
Any idea on how to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the `autoresize` option listed in the `plugins` items? It should have no impact but you may try removing it to see if it helps...

Another thing that may be impairing your editor resizing capability may be in the class `well` you used in the `<div>` that embeds the `<textarea>`. It if has any CSS *position* defined or *display* option set as `flex`, it may disrupt some of the editor's visual functionalities (especially the ones related to sizing and positioning).

Also, here some small suggestions for your **TinyMCE Init** settings:

```
tinymce.init({ 
     selector    :'#client_report',
     resize      : true,   // Good, it is set right :)
     // theme_advanced_resizing: true  // Not needed, as it is theme specific

     // ** Other interesting options (use as needed) **
     branding    : false,  // Remove the "Powered by Tiny"
     elementpath : false,  // Stop showing the selected element TAG 
     statusbar   : true    // Set the statusbar as visible (yes, you can hide it)
});
```

You can check my answer about TinyMCE 5 related to resizing, it may bring you some additional ideas and options: [How to automatic resize tinyMCE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799123/how-to-automatic-resize-tinymce)

Answer (score 0):

`theme_advanced_resizing` isn't an option in v5.

Other than that, it seems to work fine in a simple example:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/JDgaab

Resize is `true` by default, so you should only need to set it if you want `both`.

Comment: Thanks Spyder, I saw the link but it doesn't fix my problem. As soon as I click the corner, the mouse cursor change from double-arrow (hover), to default (click). It looks like some JS is preventing the editor to resize. Really strange, I tried without 'well' and same result. Even if I set the height of the editor in CSS, I can't change it further by dragging the corner..

Comment: I've resolved by adding a Jquery event linked to a range slider (not ideal, but it works)

Comment: That's very strange! So you see that even on the fiddle? Which browser are you using? That might be a bug, perhaps we should take this to a [github ticket](http://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues) :)